# Keeping List<T> as function parameter gives warning

Tags: c#, .net, collections, msdn, generic-list

On running Code analysis, I am getting a warning for a function.

function signature is : `public int ExecuteAscommand(List<string> Commands)`

Warning message is :  Change List to Collection,Readonlycollection or
KeyedCollection.

MSDN explains this scenario as List is perfromance optmizied, but not designed for inheritance .And suppress this warning 
only if it is not used as a reusable library.

My function does nothing more than reading all the items from the list and perform a task with the data. and nothing else.
But this function is part of a reusable library I am building.

Should I change the parameter type from List to any of the other types ?

Answer (score 4):

If you are only enumerating (reading all) commands, your interface should be of type `IEnumerable<string>`. That way, your user can pass anything that implements that interface: an array, a list, a collection or anything else that can be put into a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you expose your collection as an IList or anything similar, you can use the List as the actual backing-store, but you retain future extensibility as you can swap out the concerete implementation later without changing the public contract of your class.

Whereas List is not designed to be easily extensible by subclassing it; the main purpose of List is to be fast for internal implementations. You'll notice the methods on it are not virtual.